# Printing quotes arround strings from "cat" output in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df<-data.frame(S1=c(rep("A:A",10),rep("G:G ",10)),
           S2=c(rep("A:A",10),rep("G:G",10)),
           S3=c(rep("A:A",10),rep("T:T", 10)),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You might have noticed that the "G:G" on S1 has a space at the end, thats deliberate.

And I have a function that applies "unique" to all columns of a data frame and returns a table with all the unique values per column.

Function:

```
loop.unique<-function(df){
     w<-create.df(x=capture.output(for (i in colnames(df)){
        cat(unique(df[[i]]),"\n")}),
     y=c("unique.vals"))
     z<-create.df(x=colnames(df),y=c("col"))
     v<-cbind(z,w)
    return(v)
}
```

Output:

```
   col unique.vals
1  S1   A:A G:G  
2  S2    A:A G:G 
3  S3    A:A T:T
```

On larger datsets the clear distinction for the "GG " string on S1 is not so obvious, so I would like the output to look more like "print(unique(df)", as in this function:

```
loop.unique.extra<-function(df){
    for (i in colnames(df)){
       print(unique(df[[i]]),na.print="<NA>")
 }
}
```

Which Gives this output:

```
[1] "A:A"  "G:G "
[1] "A:A" "G:G"
[1] "A:A" "T:T"
```

Here, I can clearly see the extra space at the end of the GG string on S1

And what I would like to see is something like:

```
1 S1 "A:A"  "G:G "
2 S2 "A:A" "G:G"
3 S3 "A:A" "T:T"
```

Comment: have you tried `t(sapply(df,unique))`

Comment: Jeez, so simple, thanks